# How to define own js function for getting computed style of html elements

Tags: javascript, css, function, styles

```
let element = id('mydiv'); // id() is element Selector by id
let style = getComputedStyle(element);
let eleHeight = parseInt(style.height);
```

I know I can get any style value using the js code above.

Now focus on the following.

```
function getCSS(css, element) {
    return parseInt(getComputedStyle(element).css);
}
```

// usage

```
let eleHeight = getCSS('height', id('mydiv')); // but it will return 'NaN'
```

I am trying to create my own instantiated function to do this.
Please make it workable

Comment: Consider not putting the key in the file name, but use a query parameter instead? `http://anyweb.ext/media/filename.mp4?key=XXXX`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a string for the CSS property as object keys can be used like arrays or using the "dot" way.

```
function getCSS(css, element) {
    return parseInt(getComputedStyle(element)[css]);
}

let eleHeight = getCSS("height", id('mydiv'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The only problem was defining the CSS property. Now I understand. **Thanks again man**...